How to get the previous ViewModel by interface in Hilt?
I want to create a Repository during navigation and pass it forward for functions that need it so I can reuse this functionality in other places.
I'm using @AssistedInject and obtaining the previous ViewModel using hiltViewModel(parentEntry) method. When I specify concrete ViewModel everything works for that particular ViewModel but I need to access this feature from different ViewModels. Are there any other ways to achieve this?
UI GitHub
composable(route = NavRoute.SharedFeature.path) {
    val parentEntry = remember(it) {
        navController.previousBackStackEntry!!
    }
    // val parentViewModel: ModuleViewModel (interface) = hiltViewModel(parentEntry) - error
    // val parentViewModel: Module2ViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry) - works
    val parentViewModel: Module1ViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry)

    val childViewModel = hiltViewModel<SharedFeatureViewModel, SharedFeatureViewModel.Factory> { factory ->
        factory.create(parentViewModel.repository)
    }
    SharedFeatureScreen(childViewModel)
}

interface ModuleViewModel {
    val repository : Repository
}

@HiltViewModel
class Module1ViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel(), ModuleViewModel {
    override val repository: Repository = Module1RepositoryImpl()
}

@HiltViewModel
class Module2ViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel(), ModuleViewModel {
    override val repository: Repository = Module2RepositoryImpl()
}


@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = SharedFeatureViewModel.Factory::class)
class SharedFeatureViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(@Assisted private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    fun get() : String {
        return repository.get()
    }
    
    @AssistedFactory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(repository: Repository): SharedFeatureViewModel
    }
}

class Module1RepositoryImpl : Repository() {
    override fun get(): String {
        return "hi from module 1 repository"
    }
}

class Module2RepositoryImpl : Repository() {
    override fun get(): String {
        return "hi from module 2 repository"
    }
}

